# Best practice - How to implement an user authentication layer with multiple services?

Tags: authentication, codeigniter, single-sign-on

I'm developing a website with Codeigniter that's probably going to relate and connect with multiple services and frameworks:

- Magento for e-commerce
- Wordpress for Blogging
- Maybe Buddypress for more social features
- Mailchimp for Newsletter delivery
- I shouldn't forget about Facebook Connect, I guess...

Maybe it's a messy approach but I try to avoid inventing the wheel. And prefer to use the best software for the task. The thing is I will need an authentication layer to share an user object between all the services. My goal is to have a single register form that will grant you access to all services (shopping, blogging, subscribing to the newsletter).

I'm thinking I should have my own user database and a global authentication system (is there something open-source?). Then, users on the services are created behind the scenes. Any ideas on how to approach this task?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have separate login database in order to manage all your application, first you need to develop a common library to share user authentication layer, 
So you can manage n application with just one user database

Naser

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find a lot of Single Sign On libraries or modules to help you with the SSO part, but you'll probably have to manually have them talk to the same tables and fields to make it work.

I would suggest you start with setting up your simple SSO with facebook, google and the others for your user information to external services like MailChimp and then google for third-party addons with 'single sign on' as keywords for whatever application you need to have working together.. This could enable you to extend your magento, wordpress or whataver installation to communicate with eachother.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was really hoping some more answers because my question does not hava a correct answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what other answers you can get - the above mentioned applications doesn't by default enable you to create a global login for your network - and it will be an overwhelming task to implement it. It's not possible to write simple code samples that works on the fly. Using some existing SSO technology like OpenId or Facebook connect would be the best approach.